# Laravel обрезание текса в php с сохранением слов

Tags: php, laravel

как вывести из базы с обрезанием по символам, желательно слова не отрезать

```
<table class="table">
 <tbody>
  @foreach ($post as $article)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$article->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$article->title}}</td>
      <td>{{$article->slug}}</td>
      <td>{{$article->content}}</td>
      <td>{{$article->created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Posts;

class Blog extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
      $post = Posts::orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);  

      return view('admin.pages.index')->withPost($post);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порекомендую [хорошие практики написания кода в контексте Laravel](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md), а также одельно обращаю внимание на [соглашение по именованию](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8), т.к. заметил по-видимому модель c именем `Posts` (рекомендуется называть модели в единственном числе, а таблицы - во множественном)

Можно создать [акцессор](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) в модели для формирования отформатированного по длине контента

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Post extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected function getShortContentAttribute()
    {
        // 1. Str::words() - обрезает строку по количеству слов, переданному вторым параметром
        // 2. Просто совет, основанный на практике: "внутри" модели к атрибутам обращаемся 
        // либо через ArrayAccess ($this['name']), 
        // либо используя метод getAttribute ($this->getAttribute('name'))

        return Str::words((string)$this['content'], 10);
    }
}
```

В шаблоне

```
<table class="table">
 <tbody>
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$article->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->slug}}</td>
      <!--выводим short_content (camel_case) -->
      <td>{{$post->short_content}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```